# How to collapse Pandas Dataframe Columns and Concatenate Strings

Tags: pandas, dataframe, paste

I have a Data Frame df0 with n columns.
Only one of the columns contains a string, all other columns are empty or contain the "" string.

Is it possible to collapse the data frame into a single column data frame where for each row I get the non-empty element?

df0:

```
    A    B     C
1  Car
2  Car 
3       Bike
4  Car
5            Train
6            Train
```

should give:

```
    1    
1  Car
2  Car 
3  Bike
4  Car
5  Train
6  Train
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe:

```
>>> df.max(axis=1)
1      Car
2      Car
3     Bike
4      Car
5    Train
6    Train
dtype: object
```

which is a `Series`, not a `DataFrame`, but you could make one using `df.max(axis=1).to_frame(1)` or something.

Answer (score 4):

If they are empty strings rather than NaN you can use .sum:

```
In [11]: df.fillna('').sum(1)
Out[11]: 
1      Car
2      Car
3     Bike
4      Car
5    Train
6    Train
dtype: object
```

Comment: As an aside: I was surprised that just doing sum(1) didn't work - I expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

This would also work, under the assumption there's always a column with a non empty string:

```
 df.apply(lambda x: [y for y in x.values if y!=''][0],axis=1)
```