# How to collapse multiple columns pandas

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas

I have data like so and am using pandas/excel/python.

```
A     B     C     D
Bus        Car
Plane
                 Car
     Boat  Car 
     Boat  Car   Plane
```

I'm trying to get my data like so:

```
A     B     C     D
Bus  Car
Plane
Car
Boat Car
Boat Car  Plane
```

Where values (strings) get shifted over depending on if the cell is blank.

I've looked into df.max but it doesn't seem to cater to multiple columns as well as other suggestions on [How to collapse Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491845/how-to-collapse-pandas-dataframe-columns-and-concatenate-strings)

I'm not looking to concatenate strings, just shift everything over.

I saw a method using "R" and melt, however I would like to stick with python/pandas if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: When I use `pd.read_clipboard()` in `pandas` to copy the first `DataFrame`, I immediately get the result you desire. I guess this is because its default is to parse values separated by spaces and only startes the separating process from the moment it sees the first value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
print df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[~x.isnull()].values), axis=1)
       0    1      2
0    Bus  Car    NaN
1  Plane  NaN    NaN
2    Car  NaN    NaN
3   Boat  Car    NaN
4   Boat  Car  Plane
```

You can always `fillna()` the resultant with blanks.

Answer (score 0):

Clumsy, but working:

```
df.apply(lambda x:
         pd.DataFrame([[i for i in x if i], ['' for i in x]], columns=x.index).ix[0],
         axis=1)
```

This part `pd.DataFrame([[i for i in x if i], ['' for i in x]], columns=x.index).ix[0]` is needed for preserving the original shape and columns.